# SAS Latex Destination: Suppress SAS escape chars

Tags: sas

When I run the following and output to the ODS Latex desination, SAS escapes the dollar sign and all the brackets, which won't compile in Latex.

How can I output what's in each cell verbatim?

```
ods escapechar='^';

Proc format;
picture sigstar (round)
    low-0.01="***" (NOEDIT)
    0.01<-0.05="** " (FILL=' ' PREFIX='')
    0.05<-0.10="*  " (FILL=' ' PREFIX='')
    other=     " " (FILL=' ' PREFIX='');
run;

data test;
   input mean pvalue;
   datalines; 
   2.50 0.001
   3.50 0.05
   4.25 0.12
   5.00 0.01
   ;
run;

data test;
   set test;
   output = cats( put(mean,7.2)  , '{$^{', put(pvalue,sigstar.),'}$}' );
   format pvalue sigstar.;
   drop mean pvalue;
run;

ods tagsets.simplelatex file="test.tex" (notop nobot);
   proc print data=test;run;
ods tagsets.simplelatex close;
```

This outputs the following .text code:

```
\sassystemtitle[c]{~}
\sascontents[1]{The Print Procedure}
\sascontents[2]{Data Set WORK.TEST}


\begin{longtable}{|r|l|r|}\hline
   Obs &    output &    pvalue\\\hline
\endhead
   1 &    2.50\{\$\^\{***\}\$\} &    ~\\\hline
   2 &    3.50\{\$\^\{**\}\$\} &    ~\\\hline
   3 &    4.25\{\$\^\{\}\$\} &    ~\\\hline
   4 &    5.00\{\$\^\{***\}\$\} &    ~\\\hline
\end{longtable}
```

How can I ensure that the second cell in the first row shows `2.50{$^{***}$}`  and not `2.50\{\$\^\{***\}\$\}`? The package I'm using in Latex requires that the stars are surrounded by the chars above, so I just want to output what's in the dataset verbatim.

Comment: Try using an ODS Escapechar sequence just over the part you want to put in manually - I think using a custom tagset event is best but perhaps you can work around with that.

Comment: @Close voter - This is really a SAS question, not an appropriate question for [tex.se] as far as I understand.  Using other languages to generate *tex code is still appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid these characters being escaped it suffices to edit the following lines at the end of the SimpleLatex tagset:

```
mapsub = %nrstr("/\%%/$/\&/\~/\\#/{\textunderscore}");
map = %nrstr("%%$&~#_");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you would generally do that in latex tagsets.  The point of tagsets is to take normal SAS data and reformat it to make a latex file; what you're doing is manually doing the latex file itself.

[This paper](http://www.phusewiki.org/docs/2008/PAPERS/TU04.pdf) shows an example of how you can do something close to what you want; basically, you write the latex file sans-SAS provided graphs or charts, mark where you want the SAS part to go, and effectively paste it in via SAS code.  You should also be able to do the writing of the initial latex file in SAS - but don't do it with the tagset, just write it directly in a data step put.

The easiest way, though, may be to simply customize your own latex tagset.  Edit the one closest to what you are looking for, and add in your own code as needed.  An example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701239/sas-custom-ods-latex-tagset).

Comment: I used `tagset.simplelatex` here for clarity. I did customize my own latex tagset and I just output the contents of the rows usually. In this instance, I want to append stars to a variable in SAS and the syntax for the `siunitx` package that aligns stars is, for example, `2.50{$^{***}$}`. There is a line in `tagsets.latex` that I'm trying to override, but it doesn't seem to work: `map = %nrstr("%%$&{}~^#_\");` Putting the stars in a separate column would ruin the formatting of all my tables. . .

Comment: Edit your question to show what you are trying to do in detail. I think the answer will be some sort of inline formatting event or perhaps directly applied inline formatting.

Comment: Also, just realized I linked to your own question from a while ago- not paying attention apparently.  Either way, more information in the question for the actual question would help.

Comment: I added more detail in the question there.

Comment: What is your ODS ESCAPECHAR set to?

Comment: I tried both `^` and `~`. `ods escapechar='^';` or `ods escapechar='~';` It only seems to make a difference in the HTML window, not in the latex output.